# Differences between Reactive Programming and Message Queue

Tags: java, queue, jms, reactive-programming

I'm busy with **Reactive** concept these days. I have understood two separate concepts as **Reactive System** and **Reactive Programming**. In addition, I know **Reactive System** is a larger concept which contains four properties:

1. Responsive
2. Resilient
3. Scalable
4. Event-Driven

[image]

*The Image Reference: medium.com*

My problem is about **Reactive Programming**, I understood that its goal is Asynchronous Programming by Observable/Subscriber model.
[image]

*The Image Reference: https://hub.packtpub.com/introduction-reactive-programming/*

Now I'm confused about the difference between **Reactive Programming** and **Message Queue**. I have had some experience in **Message Oriented Middleware** and related standards such as **JMS** and I think **Reactive Programming** is the same using messaging queue in listener mode not blocking mode.

I wanted to be clear in **Reactive Programming** real concept.

Comment: In asynchronous models, message queue is a middleware which facilitates publishing messages and then subscribing to these messages. Similarly a queue will be a component of the ecosystem which achieves reactive programming.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Reactive Programming is a new name for old concepts. It means prefer event-driven computing over request-reply computing. Or 'push' versus 'pull'. So instead of writing code that waits for something to arrive, you define callbacks that are executed when something happens. The **Observer pattern** is a good example of reactive programming and so is the **Hollywood Principle** ("Don't call us, we'll call you").

In JMS terms, you are doing reactive programming if you defined a MessageListener on your consumer: `MessageConsumer.setMessageListener(MessageListener listener)`

Then your API or other code can decide what to process in the meantime and if something arrives, from a queue or topic, that callback is invoked.

The alternative, using `MessageConsumer.receive(long timeout)`, is not reactive programming. You are blocking your current thread until the next message arrives.

Thinking in an event-driven or reactive way takes a bit of a leap sometimes, but it is worth the effort.

When looking at the system itself, I would argue that an infrastructure built with topics is a *reactive system*. An infrastructure built with queues is not.

Answer (score 1):

In synchronous programming, `blocking queues` are widely used. If consumer does not manage to process messages in timely manner, `blocking queue` suspends producer thread in order to avoid excessive consumption of memory for messages.

In synchronous world, thread blocking must be avoided, so `blocking queues` are not acceptable. Instead, `reactive streams` are used, which inform producer how many messages it is allowed to send.

Technically, a `reactive stream` is a usual stream of messages plus backward stream of `permissions`. `Permissions` are like undistinguishable messages, which need not to be stored, but only counted. In synchronous world, `permissions` are stored (counted) by `java.lang.Semaphore` and `java.lang.CountdownLatch`. Unfortunately, most asynchronous libraries do not provide developer with separate constructs to handle `permissions`. The only exception I know is my own library `df4j` (can be found at Github).

Except for (implicit) notion of asynchronous semaphore, I could not find any other sense in all that `reactive programming` hype.